# Ubuntu showing clearing orphaned inode and not turning on

Tags: linux, ubuntu, orphaned-objects

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58qnE.jpg)

I restart my laptop with Ubuntu installed in. After taking some time it starts showing me message " /dev/sad7: Clearing orphaned inode 12981277 etc.

I searched on Google about it but I found nothing convening.
Anyone know what's wrong with my laptop?

Comment: Just wait a few minutes. It looks like it is performing filesystem check and didn't finished yet.

Comment: It's been like an hour. Any guess how long more it might take?

Comment: Do you have some 'drive activity' indicator? Is it on?

Comment: Yes, light is still on!

Comment: So it looks it's working. If your system is not completely frozen (e.g. your CapsLock or NumLock keys work, switching theirs indicators), I'd wait.

Comment: Capslock indicator is  frozen and num lock indicator is working!

Comment: So I'd assume that the system is still alive and I'd wait.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se] would be better places for questions like this.